# Vue.js Error in render: "TypeError: router is undefined"

Tags: vue.js

I've been searching up and down all over the place for an answer to this. I'm trying to set up routes in Vue.js. I'm very new at Vue.js, so please bear with with me here.

The error is this:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: router is undefined"

found in

---> <RouterLink>
       <SideNav> at src/components/SideNav.vue
```

I'm going to simplify the because the nav is fairly complex and renders correctly as long as I use standard anchors. I simplified the issue down to this:

```
<template>
     <router-link to="/">home</router-link>
</template>

<script>

  import axios from 'axios'
  import Vue from 'vue'

export default ({
  data () {
    return {
  nav: null,
    }
  },
  mounted () {
  axios
  .get('http://localhost:3000/sidenav')
  .then(result => (this.nav = result))
  }
})</script>
```

If I use standard `<a href="/">Home</a>`, I do not get the error.

If put `<router-link to="/">home</router-link>` in the `index.html` file, I do not get the above error. My main.js file looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import SideNav from './components/SideNav.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    render: h => h(SideNav),
}).$mount('#sidenav')
....
{ router stuff that's not important for now }
```

The index.html is standard, this is the block I'm attempting to inject into:

```
<div class="grid-x">
  <div id="sidenav" class="cell small-6"></div>
  <div id="infodiv" class="cell small-6"></div>
  <div id="notationdiv" class="cell small-6"></div>
</div>
```

I found some information that this could be a config issue, so my vue.config.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    devServer: {
        proxy: 'https://localhost:3000/',
    },
    // resolve: {
    //     alias: {
    //         'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' for webpack 1
    //     }
    // }
}
```

It's the default config except I added `runtimeCompiler: true` The commented area causes an error, so it's not running.

Seems that there are 100s of examples where my pattern should be working fine, but apparently I'm missing something here. I did try adding `VueRouter` to `SideNav.vue` to no avail.

Comment: You should be passing a router instance as a config option to `new Vue`. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript

Comment: @skirtle Looks like that solved it, or at least shows a hole in my thinking. Thanks a lot.